# statistic generation in use-case-diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I have use cases where the user can browse  statistics.
The statistic should be generated automatically every 10 secs.

[image]

Whats the best way to model the dependency between `view statistic` and `generate statistic`?
So the user can change the interval or something else in the statistic generation.

Or should I remove `generate statistic` from the use case diagram?

___UPDATE

And what happens when I have one more use case for controlling the statistic generation? Would there be a stroke between `generate statistic` and `control statistic` generation or not?

Answer (score 2):

The statistics a generated by a different actor (say `Scheduler`). So this needs to be the actor for this use case.

[image]

If something else controls creation of statistics you can go via Generalization:
[image]

Comment: This is the same approach like taking a Time Actor or?

Comment: Time is a measure (as Einstein said, it's what you can read on you watch). You can call it Timer, however ;-)

Answer (score 1):

DON'T remove Generate statistics. It is important part of functionality, a separate use case and removing it will confuse the actual functionality.
As @thomaskilian already provided answer how to handle Generate statistics it I'll not repeat it here.
Second important information - even though all mentioned use cases (View statistics, Generate statistics and Control statistics) are related to statistics as such, as behaviours they are separate and they are NOT related. So no relationship on diagrams.
Of course the statistics generation depends on current objects  related to statistic generation while Control statistics changes those objects. Similarly Generate statistics generates object of type Statistics and View statistics gives possibility to view those objects, but those relations are only on data level. The behaviours (use cases) don't interact directly.